# Exact Sine/Cosine/Tangent of Various Angles

Tags: python, math

Is there a way to get the exact Tangent/Cosine/Sine of an angle (in radians)?

`math.tan()`/`math.sin()`/`math.cos()` does not give the exact for some angles:

```
>>> from math import *
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> sin(pi) # should be 0
1.2246467991473532e-16
>>> sin(2*pi) # should be 0
-2.4492935982947064e-16
>>> cos(pi/2) # should be 0
6.123233995736766e-17
>>> cos(3*pi/2) # 0
-1.8369701987210297e-16
>>> tan(pi/2) # invalid; tan(pi/2) is undefined
1.633123935319537e+16
>>> tan(3*pi/2) # also undefined
5443746451065123.0
>>> tan(2*pi) # 0
-2.4492935982947064e-16
>>> tan(pi) # 0
-1.2246467991473532e-16
```

I tried using Decimal(), but this does not help either:

```
>>> tan(Decimal(pi)*2)
-2.4492935982947064e-16
```

`numpy.sin(x)` and the other trigonometric functions also have the same issue.

Alternatively, I could always create a new function with a dictionary of values such as:

```
def new_sin(x):
    sin_values = {math.pi: 0, 2*math.pi: 0}
    return sin_values[x] if x in sin_values.keys() else math.sin(x)
```

However, this seems like a cheap way to get around it. Is there any other way? Thanks!

Comment: When using finite length representations of floating point numbers, there is no way to exactly represent irrational numbers. The results of trig functions are quite often irrational, so there's no way to exactly represent them on digital computers. What you are seeing is a limitation of floating point numbers, and if the values are not close enough to 0 for you for your problem, you probably need to rethink how you are approaching the solution for it.

Comment: More importantly, `math.pi` is not exactly `pi`, so even if the `sin` were exact, it still wouldn't be `0`.

Comment: This is due to the limitations of floating point calculations.  There are a few ways to deal with this.  Symbolic calculations, adjusting the precision approriately, etc.  If you say what you want it for, there might be a solution.

Comment: That's the nature of floating point, and you can't get around it. Even the dict lookup is only good for certain cases. For example (52*math.pi) / 52 != math.pi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is impossible to store the exact numerical value of pi in a computer. `math.pi` is the closest approximation to pi that can be stored in a Python float. `math.sin(math.pi)` returns the correct result for the approximate input.

To avoid this, you need to use a library that supports symbolic arithmetic. For example, with sympy:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> sin(pi)
0
>>> pi
pi
>>>
```

sympy will operate on an object that represents pi and can give exact results.

Comment: This is a great solution for most use cases. If you need the approximate numeric value, you can get it, but avoid doing so as long as possible.

Comment: This is probably what you called necromancing but wouldn't this be enough to solve your problem?:

import numpy as np
from math import pi

def sin(x):
    if x/pi == int(x/pi):
        return 0
    elif x/pi != int(x/pi):
        return np.sin(x)

Comment: @DavidM.Sousa Not really a good solution since `int((11*math.pi)/math.pi)` is 10.

Comment: @casevh The fact that it is 10 is irrelevant in this case, since either 10 or 11 would give 0. int((11*math.pi)/math.pi) is in fact int(10.99999999999) which is naturaly 10.

Answer (score 3):

When you're dealing with inexact numbers, you need to deal with error explicitly. `math.pi` (or `numpy.pi`) isn't exactly `π`, it's, e.g., the closest binary rational number in 56 digits to `π`. And the `sin` of that number is not `0`.

But it is *very close* to 0. And likewise, `tan(pi/2)` is not infinity (or NaN), but huge, and `asin(1)/pi` is very close to 0.5.

So, even if the algorithms were somehow exact, the results still wouldn't be exact.

If you've never read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), you should do so now.

The way to deal with this is to use epsilon-comparisons rather than exact comparisons everywhere, and explicitly round things when printing them out, and so on.

Using [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) numbers instead of `float` numbers makes this easier. First, you probably think in decimal rather than binary, so it's easier for you to understand and make decisions about the error. Second, you can explicitly set precision and other context information on `Decimal` values, while `float` are always IEEE double values.

The *right* way to do it is to do full error analysis on your algorithms, propagate the errors appropriately, and use that information where it's needed. The *simple* way is to just pick some explicit absolute or relative epsilon (and the equivalent for infinity) that's "good enough" for your application, and use that everywhere. (You'll probably also want to use the appropriate domain-specific knowledge to treat some values as multiples of `pi` instead of just raw values.)